# Суммирование данных в определенном столбце, из отсортированных строк

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[Есть](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php) большой ООП-файл "MysqliDb.php".

Подскажите, какая именно функция в нем отвечает за суммирование 
данных в определенном столбце, из отсортированных строк? Из phpmyAdmin.
Просмотрел все, не смог понять какая из них.

Пример: надо суммировать все значения столбца 'price', в таблице 'models'. При этом была сортировка моделей, где параметр 'model_id' == $model_id;

```
$db->where('model_id', $model_id);
$summa = $db->getValue('models','price');
```

Я думал это функция 'getValue', но она взяла только ОДНО последнее значение!

Comment: взято у `joshcam` .... в его профиле написано `josh.lee.campbell@gmail.com` - напишите и спросите....... также на гитхабе есть комменты и `issues` ....... напишите и спросите......ведь автор наверняка знает определенно точно, нежели прохожие в виде обитателей ресурсов

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  Ясно! Я думал это популярный ООП-файл и многие его используют, но видно я ошибался! ОК!

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ:

```
$db->where('model_id', $model_id);
$summa = $db->getValue('models', 'sum(price)');
echo 'total price: ' . $summa;
```